# WPF ProgressBar Not Updating with INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datacontext, inotifypropertychanged

I have a UserControl with several TextBox controls and a ProgressBar. The TextBox controls properly reflect the properties in codebehind to which they are bound. The ProgressBar does not respond to property change, however.

My XAML:

```
<UserControl
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:Cmc.Installer.Controls;assembly=Cmc.Installer.Controls" x:Class="Cmc.Installer.Modules.MobileRecruiter.MobileRecruiterModule" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="600" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="580" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="780">
        <Canvas>
            <Label Content="Database Server" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding DatabaseServer}" Height="23" Canvas.Left="160" Canvas.Top="12" Width="160"/>
            <Label Content="Database Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="38"/>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding DatabaseName}" Height="23" Canvas.Left="160" Canvas.Top="40" Width="160"/>
            <Label Content="Database Username" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="66"/>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding DatabaseUsername}" Height="23" Canvas.Left="160" Canvas.Top="68" Width="160"/>
            <Label Content="Database Password" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="94"/>
            <Controls:BindablePasswordBox Password="{Binding DatabasePassword}" Height="23" Canvas.Left="160" Canvas.Top="96" Width="160"/>
            <ProgressBar Name="ProgressBar" Value="{Binding Progress}" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="164" Width="760" Height="24" />
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And its codebehind (very abbreviated):

```
public partial class MobileRecruiterModule : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private static readonly Logger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    private int _progress;

    public MobileRecruiterModule()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    public string DatabaseServer { get; set; }
    public string DatabaseName { get; set; }
    public string DatabaseUsername { get; set; }
    public string DatabasePassword { get; set; }

    public int Progress
    {
        get { return _progress; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _progress) return;
            _progress = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Progress");
            Logger.Trace("Progress.set() = " + _progress);
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    // This is called by an external class
    public void OnProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        Progress = args.ProgressPercentage;
    }

}
```

I know the value of `Progress` is changing because I see it in the NLog logs:

```
2014-04-17 16:22:54.4068|TRACE|Cmc.Installer.Modules.MobileRecruiter.MobileRecruiterModule|Progress.set() = 28
```

I don't understand why the ProgressBar doesn't update when I fire `OnPropertyChanged` in the setter just before the logging call.

Comment: How do you update your `Progress` property?

Comment: Through my own custom event handler. I've updated my example above.

Comment: Did you try executing the update in a dispatcher thread?  The DB activity may be giving the pb a chance to update the UI.

Comment: @GarryVass Don't need to. WPF is smart enough to marshal it to the UI thread.

Comment: @GarryVass there is no DB in this application. The progress just happens to be updated by a WCF callback. That part is totally irrelevant though.

Comment: try to bind to a textblock text and see if it updates...just to know if it is from the progress bar

Comment: there are no binding errors in the console or anything?

Comment: TextBlock does not update either. It just shows a zero (0) the whole time: `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Progress}" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="193" Width="760" Height="23"></TextBlock>`

Comment: @MarkRichman, if the UI is being blocked, it becomes very relevant.

Comment: I believe it could be caused by the way you're actually using this UserControl, and that the DataContext isn't what you think it is. Try adding `Logger.Trace(DataContext.ToString())` to your setter and see what it tells you. Showing the xaml that uses the usercontrol will also help.

Comment: are you getting exceptions in some of the delegate code? it seems like you might be getting cross thread exceptions when you try to update progress or fire the progress event?

Answer (score 2):

I replicated a scaled down version of your app in an MVVM pattern and had good luck with it.  I used this code to replicate your user control...

```
<UserControl x:Class="ProgressBarBinding.Login"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="580" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="780">
        <Canvas>
            <Label Content="Database Server" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding DatabaseServer}" Height="23" Canvas.Left="160" Canvas.Top="12" Width="160"/>
            <Label Content="Database Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="38"/>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding DatabaseName}" Height="23" Canvas.Left="160" Canvas.Top="40" Width="160"/>
            <Label Content="Database Username" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="66"/>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding DatabaseUsername}" Height="23" Canvas.Left="160" Canvas.Top="68" Width="160"/>
            <Label Content="Database Password" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="94"/>
            <ProgressBar Name="ProgressBar" Value="{Binding Progress}" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="164" Width="760" Height="24" />
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The only thing missing from that is your proprietary password control, which does not affect the solution.

I encoded this control into a MainWindow.xaml file thusly...

```
<Window x:Class="ProgressBarBinding.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ProgressBarBinding"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <vm:ViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource ViewModel}">
        <vm:Login/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Note that the window resource definition includes a reference to a view model instance.  Most people set up MVVM with dependency injection, but this approach is good for quick trials and **`Indicative Code`**.  The view model is set as the Grid's data context.  **Your control inherits the data context from the grid.** That's the end of the xaml code.  There is no code-behind in the MainWindow.xaml.cs file other than the call to InitializeComponent (and that's where the VM instance gets created).

The ViewModel class looks like this...

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly SynchronizationContext _synchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    public ViewModel()
    {
        DatabaseServer = "AnyServer";
        DatabaseName = "Any name";
        Model m = new Model();
        Task.Run(() => m.DoWork(this));
    }
    public string DatabaseServer { get; set; }
    public string DatabaseName { get; set; }
    public string DatabaseUsername { get; set; }
    public string DatabasePassword { get; set; }
    private int _progress;
    public int Progress
    {
        get { return _progress; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _progress) return;
            _progress = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Progress");
            Console.WriteLine(@"Progress.set() = " + _progress);
        }
    }
    // This is called by an external class
    public void OnProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        _synchronizationContext.Send(delegate { Progress = args.ProgressPercentage; }, null);
    }
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Implementation
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        var handler = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref PropertyChanged, null, null);
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Most of the code in the view model looks like yours except there are no dependencies on UI elements.  Everything is done via binding.  I used a SynchronizationContext in the callback, although it may not be necessary in your application.

The constructor of the VM starts a model on a TPL thread.  The model looks like this...

```
public class Model
{
    public void DoWork(ViewModel vm)
    {
        int progressPercentage = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            vm.OnProgressChanged(this, new ProgressChangedEventArgs(progressPercentage, null));
            if (i%1000 == 0)
            {
                ++progressPercentage;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So putting it all together, the model is running in its own thread, and the UI is being updated on its own thread.  The whole thing works as expected.

The ProgressBar will increment its way up to 100 and the UI will remain responsive while the model is doing its work.  This answer does not explain why your original code does not work, but I suspect it has to do with the UI thread being starved out.  This is evidenced by your complete log history, but nothing changing on the UI.  Overall, this answer moves toward what others have suggested in their commentary: namely that the MVVM approach of binding has a lot to offer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're in a UserControl, you need to explicitly give it a name and use the **ElementName** tag when binding, like this:

```
<UserControl
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:Cmc.Installer.Controls;assembly=Cmc.Installer.Controls" x:Class="Cmc.Installer.Modules.MobileRecruiter.MobileRecruiterModule" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="600" d:DesignWidth="800" x:Name="MyControl">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="580" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="780">
        <Canvas>
            <ProgressBar Name="ProgressBar" Value="{Binding Progress, ElementName=MyControl}" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="164" Width="760" Height="24" />
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: This unfortunately had no effect, and I had to remove the quotes around `ElementName="MyControl"` to get it to compile: `Value="{Binding Progress, ElementName=MyControl}"`

Comment: did you make sure you set the x:Name tag inside the UserControl declaration?

Comment: i did indeed...would you explain why this would be required for a UserControl? I'm new to WPF, so I still think in Winforms.

Comment: and the OP is doing `DataContext = this;` so binding to itself *should* work without using elementname

Answer (score -1):

Why do you need `Binding` if you have the `Actual control`. Since you are not doing it in `MVVM` just call the `ProgressBar` right away.

```
ProgressBar.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => ProgressBar.Value = Progress = args.ProgressPercentage);
```

Sorry but I don't see the benefit of the `Binding` if all the properties/controls are accessible in your `View`'s class.

Binding is more useful and powerful if you implemented `MVVM`.

Comment: I plan to implement MVVM, but this application is a prototype. I'm just trying to understand why the binding isn't working.

Comment: and the rest of it is using binding too, why do progress a different way?

Comment: @MarkRichman By external class, what do you mean by that? Is that running in a different thread? And are you sure it's not really updating the progress bar? Does it get stuck at Value 0 and just closes?

Comment: The value rapidly increases from 0 to 100, as evidenced by my log and breakpoint. I've got thousands of log entries showing that the `Progress` setter is being called, i.e. `2014-04-17 17:10:07.7871|TRACE|Cmc.Installer.Modules.MobileRecruiter.MobileRecruiterModule|Progress.set() = 44`

Comment: @JohnGardner Because if it is implemented the correct way then he wouldn't encounter weird scenarios like this. Using a concept that is not suppose to be used for instances like this is just not right.

Comment: What exactly isn't "right"? I have a property, a datacontext, and a binding. It *should* work.

Comment: this is exactly what databinding is for, binding values to controls. there's just something here missing that should all be working. the OP didn't come here for a design discussion, he came for help with a specific thing.

Comment: @MarkRichman But no ViewModel. Can you show who calls this `OnProgressChanged` or who raises that event?

Comment: I have a WCF callback function which invokes it via a reference to the object via its interface `_installModule`: `public void OnUpdateProgress(int progressPercentage)
        {
            Logger.Trace("OnUpdateProgress = " + progressPercentage);
            var args = new ProgressChangedEventArgs(progressPercentage, null);
            Progress = progressPercentage;
            _installModule.OnProgressChanged(this, args);
        }`

Comment: @lll You have the worst handle for sending @ replies to ;) What would a ViewModel look like here?

Comment: @MarkRichman To me, it looks like that there is something that is hogging the UI that it doesn't have the time yet to update the `ProgressBar` and just updates it when it's `100`.

Comment: @JohnGardner You'll want to use data binding to connect the object model (ViewModel) to the UI controls and not to UI view's properties.